# Ionic Error: Invalid attribute name

Tags: ionic-framework

I am trying to execute ionic command.

```
ionic cordova platform add ios
```

it gives me following error on terminal.

`Error: Invalid attribute name
Line: 12
Column: 35
Char: "
    at error (/Users/jacmacos2/Desktop/project/node_modules/sax/lib/sax.js:666:10)
    at strictFail (/Users/jacmacos2/Desktop/project/node_modules/sax/lib/sax.js:692:7)
    at Object.write (/Users/jacmacos2/Desktop/project/node_modules/sax/lib/sax.js:1330:13)
    at XMLParser.feed (/Users/jacmacos2/Desktop/project/node_modules/elementtree/lib/parsers/sax.js:48:15)
    at ElementTree.parse (/Users/jacmacos2/Desktop/project/node_modules/elementtree/lib/elementtree.js:271:10)
    at Object.parse (/Users/jacmacos2/Desktop/project/node_modules/elementtree/lib/elementtree.js:584:8)
    at Function.<anonymous> (/Users/jacmacos2/Desktop/project/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/@ionic/cli-utils/lib/cordova/config.js:29:28)
    at next (native)
project`

I don't understand what is happen.
If anyone faced this issue please tell me how to solve it.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved it.
I check my config.xml file.
The double quote was removed from there.
I just add it and complete it then issue solved.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had copied an excerpt from a web page and there was a different character instead of spaces.

I search and replaced this alternative space character and then it passed.

This is why in my case the line with the error read:

```
Error: Invalid attribute name
Line: 12
Column: 35
Char:
```

Answer (score 0):

On  my case, there is a `&` symbol on `name` property of `config.xml`. Took me a while before I figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was an unnecessary comma (,). So basically go through your code to check for any typos.